# Unable to send user data to views

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, ejs

This is my general format for views:

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<%- include('_header'); %>
<main>
(html code for a particular page)
</main>
<%- include('_footer'); %>

</body>
</html>
```

This is my code for _header.ejs:

```html
<header>
    <a id="logos" href="/">
        <img id="dr" src="/imgs/logo.png" alt="logo">
    </a>

    <div id="nav_bar">
        <a href="/achievements">Achievements</a>
        <a href="/sponsors">Sponsors</a>
        <a href="/team">Team</a>
        <a href="/gallery">Gallery</a>
        <% if(profile_user.id) { %>
            <a href="/login">Profile</a>
        <% } else { %>
            <a href="/login">Log In</a>
        <% } %>

    </div>

</header>
```

I have routes folder which gets controllers from different controllers. I am getting an error _header.ejs that profile_user.id is not defined.

```
   11|         <a href="/gallery">Gallery</a>
>> 12|         <% if(profile_user) { %> 
   13|             <a href="/login"><%= profile_user.user %></a>
   14|         <% } else { %>
   15|             <a href="/login">Log In</a>

profile_user is not defined
```

Now the solution to this problem would be to use User.findOne() but then I don't want to do this for all controllers. I want to globalize profile_user into all views. Can you tell me how to do that?

Also, I have tried to do this by adding middleware and sending using it in my app.js but it never gets called.

```
    console.log(10);
    if (await req.isAuthenticated()) {
        // req.user contains the current signed in user from the session cookie and we are just sending this to the locals for the views
        res.locals.user = req.user;
        console.log('Locals\' user loaded');
    }
    next();
}
```

In app.js I have called the function

```
app.use(passport.setAuthenticatedUser);
```

and updated the _header.ejs code to this:

```
            <a href="/login"><%= user.user %></a>
        <% } else { %>
            <a href="/login">Log In</a>
        <% } %>
```

Solution to any of the two problems (through middleware or through controllers) will do.
Let me know if you need anything else